# How to get item from Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created list using Recycler View. Now I want to get item after click. I heard about getAdapterPosition but I dont know how to use it.
I try something like this but honestly dont know how to get it.

My Fragment class code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<MovieDb> data;
    private MovieDb movieDb;
    static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;

    public static FragmentOne newInstance() {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        return fragment;
    }

    public class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MovieDb>> {
        @Override
        protected List<MovieDb> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            MovieResultsPage movies = new TmdbApi("f753872c7aa5c000e0f46a4ea6fc49b2").getMovies().getUpcoming("en-US", 1, "US");
            List<MovieDb> listMovies = movies.getResults();

            return listMovies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieDb> movieDb) {
            data = movieDb;
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(getContext());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());  // ???
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        MovieTask mt = new MovieTask();
        mt.execute();

        return returnView;
    }

    private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Context context;

        private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos1;
            pos1 = adapter.getItemId();
            movieDb = data.get(pos);
            TextView text;
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text.getText(), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Function OnClick is mess because I try a lot. I can get text from TextView but it is not what I want.

There is my Adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<MovieDb> dataSet;
    public int pos;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;
        int pos;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            this.textViewVersion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(FragmentOne.myOnClickListener);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(List<MovieDb> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

        //view.setOnClickListener(FragmentOne.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;
        pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;
        Glide.with(imageView).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + dataSet.get(listPosition).getPosterPath()).into(imageView);

        textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getOriginalTitle());
        textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getReleaseDate());
    }

    public int getPos(){
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(dataSet == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

I try to get position using `int pos` but I dont know how to use it in function OnClick.

Comment: use onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder. :)

Comment: All this class u mean? ```private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener ```

Comment: Can I open chat with u?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along these lines:

1. Adjust your `MyOnClickListener` to something like this:

   ```
    private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Context context;
    private int position;

    //Adjust your constructor to take in the context as a paramater
    private MyOnClickListener(Context context, int position) {
        this.context = context;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //not sure what you're doing with movieDB here....
        movieDb = data.get(position);
        TextView text;
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text.getText(), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   ```

   }
   }
2. Update your `CustomAdapter` class:

   ```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<MovieDb> dataSet;
    public int pos;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<MovieDb> data, Context context) {
          this.dataSet = data;
          this.context = context;
    }

    //You'll need this later to update the data set
    public void updateDataSet(List<MovieDB data){
         this.dataSet = data; 
         notifyDataSetChange();
   ```

   ...
3. In your `onBindViewHolder` do something like:

   ```
    @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
    TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;
    pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;
    Glide.with(imageView).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + dataSet.get(listPosition).getPosterPath()).into(imageView);

    textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getOriginalTitle());
    textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getReleaseDate());

    holder.setOnClickListener(new MyOnclickListener(context, listPosition));
   ```

   }
4. Move your adapter call from the `MovieTask` to the `FragmentOne` `onCreateMethod`:

   ```
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(getContext());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());  // ???
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
       adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), data);

        MovieTask mt = new MovieTask();
        mt.execute();

        return returnView;
    }
   ```
5. In your `Movie Task` update you data set:

   ```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieDb> movieDb) {
            data = movieDb;
            adapter.updateDataSet(data);
        }
   ```

You might need to make some minor adjustments to this code, but it should give you a basic idea of how to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Best of luck :)

Comment: I also dont know what I am doing with movieDb there, I dont know what to do so I try random things.

Comment: There is a problem with these line in onCreateView ```myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(getContext());```

I dont have position there, I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You don't create `myOnClickListener` in on create. It's created when you need it on `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface to retrieve a MovieDb when clicked:

```
public interface OnMovieDbClicked {
    void movieDbClicked(MovieDb movieDb);
}
```

In your adapter create a private member of this interface and a setter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private OnMovieDbClicked onMovieDbClicked;

    public setOnMovieDbClicked(OnMovieDbClicked onMovieDbClicked) {
        this.onMovieDbClicked = onMovieDbClicked;
    }
}
```

You can then use `getAdapterPosition()` in the constructor of your ViewHolder and use `onMovieDbClicked` to send the item clicked to your fragment:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Initialize your views

        itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            
            if (onMovieDbClicked != null && pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                MovieDb movieDb = dataSet.get(pos);
                onMovieDbClicked.movieDbClicked(movieDb);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you're creating your adapter in your fragment, call `setOnMovieDbClicked()` as well:

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
adapter.setOnMovieDbClicked(movieDb -> {
    // Do whatever you want with movieDb
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but about this: "You can then use getAdapterPosition() in the constructor of your ViewHolder and use onMovieDbClicked to send the item clicked to your fragment".
I can't use ```onMovieDbClicked``` and ```dataSet``` here.

Comment: They will be accessible if you remove the `static` modifier from `MyViewHolder`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ok, its fine for now, but still I dont understand last part. Where I should put this code?
I try in different places but it looks like I can't do this.

Comment: The `adpater.setOnMovieDbClicked(...` part? You can put that after you create the adapter. Formatting in comments is pretty bad so I'll update the answer to be clearer

Comment: You mean this ```adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);``` 
but I dont think its place where I should put this.
Can u look at my Fragment class code and tell me where it exactly should be?
Honestly I am out of idea.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/vgzssk
I try do this in this place. I must cast it and also problem with naming and I am confused which name I should change. Its good idea to put in OnPostExecute()? I don't know, just asking.

Comment: I would create the adapter in `onCreateView` and call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`. In your adapter create a function to set the dataset (`public void setDataSet(List<MovieDb> dataSet)`), make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`as well after setting the member variable `dataSet` (like the answer from BlackHatSamurai). In `onPostExecute` when you retrieve the list call `adapter.setDataSet(movieDb)`

Comment: The issue in your screenshot is because you have already used the name "movieDb". Rename it to something else like `adapter.setOnMovieDbClicked(movieDb2 -> ...`. Also when you define your adapter if you define it as `CustomAdapter` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter` you don't have to cast it later (and it probably shouldn't be static, same with the recyclerView variable)

Comment: It is working finally. One more question. I did this version inside OnPostExecute(). Can I open a dialog or something like that when I click?

Comment: Great! If you want to open a dialog when the item is clicked see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android) or the [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs). That code should go inside `adapter.setOnMovieDbClicked(movieDb2 -> { // Code here });`.